# Able to get some Amazon S3 objects but not all, getting 403 access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Problem Statement:

> Account A is uploading some file in  an Amazon S3 bucket in Account B. I am in account C and trying to access objects in Account B Amazon S3 bucket. I am able to access some of the files but not all.

Account A is uploading files like this

```
this.s3Client.putObject(bucketName, key, new FileInputStream(content), metadata);
this.s3Client.setObjectAcl(bucketName,  key, CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl);
```

I am only getting access denied for some of the files not all.
While I have checked Bucket Policy and lambda policy. It seems correct to me, as I am able to access other objects that were not uploaded by Account A and I feel that this issue is related to an object permission, where the uploader in s3 bucket has the exclusive access. But as we see in the above code, uploader is setting object acl to `BucketOwnerFullControl`

All the files are set to public already, also I have given access to Account C aws account canonical Id under ACL.
[image: Access is public]

ACLs

[image: ACL]

Lambda policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET/*"

        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Example permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_C:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have spent a lot of time on this and it is frustrating now. Please also let me know how can I debug these types of issues faster?

Comment: @amazing_mikha - did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the ACL or GO to S3 console and Select all files and make public. this is just a debugging step .

Comment: All the files are set to public already, also I have given access to my Account C aws account canonical Id under ACLs in Account B

Comment: If what you have said is correct then it seems the only thing left to look at is kms. Have you default encryption set up on the bucket?